# Twitter Bootstrap mobile components - best practices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

When building a responsive website using Twitter Bootstrap one can use the great JavaScript components, e.g. tabs or collapse (accordion). However, the choice of a certain component is not necessarily suitable for all devices.

In my case, in the desktop version, I make use of [tabs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs). But in the smartphone version, tabs become unusable because as soon as one has three or more of them they don't fit in one row due to the small screen size.
Instead, for the mobile version a [collapse](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse) would be a nice alternative.

My question aims at clarifying the best-practice of performing such a change. I can imagine two workarounds, but both are rather ugly and I'm wondering whether there is a cleaner solution:

1. create one tabbed content with the CSS class *visible-desktop* and one collapsed content with the CSS class *visible-phone*. This has the disadvantage that the actual tab content has to be delivered twice, and if it contains user-generated HTML code (as in my case), would lead to an W3C invalid code as soon as the user enters a HTML element with an id (since this id would appear twice on the page).
2. change from tab to collapse via JavaScript. This is not a satisfactory solution since a) it requires a javascript to be executed and b) there is much code that needs to be changed (see the differences in markup in the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this was to turn my main list menu into a drop-down for mobile phone displays.
[CSS-Tricks.com convert menu to drop down](http://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown)

I based my production code from the code above and heavily modified it to act a a slider panel for large displays and a drop down list for mobile phones.

Why consider a drop-down list for phones? On  mobile phone displays, a drop-down menu list will activate the phone's native scroll UI which looks and performs much like a native phone application would.  Utilizing a drop-down list would also reduce a lot of height commitments in your design.

When the drop-down menu is activated, the user will be automatically taken to the selected item link.

My example here:
[Menu to drop down with auto redirect](http://jsfiddle.net/9KPPf/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var sNavFirsLI2 = $(this).find("#gbl_sNav ul").children(":first-child");        
    sNavFirsLI2.each(function(){
               console.log('Outside: '+$(this).html());
    });
});var currentSnav;  sNavAccordion = new Boolean(false);  currentSnav = $("#gbl_sNav").html();

$("#removeAccordion").click(function() {
    if(sNavAccordion == true){
        var tempContents;
            $('#gbl_sNav ul').show();
            $('#gbl_sNav select').remove();
            //set Snav back to false
            sNavAccordion = false;  
    }else{
        alert('Nothing to remove');
    }
});

    $("#enableAccordion").click(function() {        
        if(sNavAccordion == false){
            $("<select />").appendTo("#gbl_sNav");
            $("<option />", {
               "selected": "selected",
               "value"   : "",
               "text"    : "Go to..."
            }).appendTo("#gbl_sNav select");
            $("#gbl_sNav a").each(function() {
             var myli = $(this);
             $("<option />", {
                 "value"   : myli.attr("href"),
                 "text"    : myli.text()
             }).appendTo("#gbl_sNav select");
            });     
        $('#gbl_sNav ul').hide();

            sNavAccordion = true;               
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });
```